# Sonarqube 5.3 - Slowness after upgrade

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-ops

After upgrading from Sonarqube 4.5.4 LTS to the 5.3, I noticed an increase of the time to process the analysis of the same project.

Looking into the logs of Backgroud task, seems that it hangs right after this line:

```
2016.04.05 16:30:26 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load measure computers | time=0ms
```

The same project was normally analyzed in 2-3 minutes when using SQ 4.5.4 but now with 5.3 it's taking 15-20 minutes.

Any idea what could explain this slowness and is there something that could fix it?

PS - I have increased the JVM arguments already to allow the usage of more memory (from 1gb to 3gb)

Thanks!

Comment: What timings are you comparing? In 4.X, analysis ran only on the analyzer side. In 5.2+, it runs both on analyzer and server side. Anyway, upgrade to 5.4, server side processing got some performance fixes. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Seb 
Thanks for the info Seb, I'll upgrade to 5.4 and reply here.
But after the execution of the analyzes I'm seeing this log:
2016.04.05 21:11:33 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load measure computers | time=0ms
2016.04.05 21:31:08 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   Execution time for each component visitor:
2016.04.05 21:31:08 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - LoadComponentUuidsHavingOpenIssuesVisitor | time=22ms
2016.04.05 21:31:08 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - IntegrateIssuesVisitor | time=1175219ms

Comment: IntegrateIssuesVisitor can be quite intensive in term of disk and DB usage. It will of course be more costly as there is more issues on project. Do you have a slow disk ? a slow DB ? a lot of issues?